# Docker failing to connect to springboot and postgres database running in the same network

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I want to containerize my spring-boot rest api together with the `postgres` database. Here is my `Dockerfile` for the `api`:

```
FROM openjdk:17

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./target/docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

CMD ["java","-jar","docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I've created a `.jar` file using `mvm`. Here is my `application.yml` file.

```yaml
# postgres sql connection
spring:
  datasource:
    password: password
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5432/todos
    username: admin
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create #create
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
# Configuring the port for our server
server:
  port: 3001
```

Here is my `docker-compose` file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgresdb:
    image: postgres:14.4-alpine
    container_name: pgsql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0_init.sql
      - $HOME/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: todos
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_NAME: postgresdb
    networks:
      - internalnet
  springboot:
    container_name: springbootserver
    build: .
    image: springboot:1.0
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    expose:
      - "3001"
    environment:
      DB_USER: "admin"
      DB_PASSWORD: "password"
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
    networks:
      - internalnet
networks:
  internalnet:
    driver: bridge
```

If i run `docker logs springbootserver`  I'm getting the following error:

```bash
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to postgresdb:5232 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting 
TCP/IP connections.
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: The line `url: jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5432/todos` from application.yml, what if you change the hostname to `127.0.0.1` to become `url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/todos`

Comment: The reason i'm using `postgresdb` it's because i'm not running it locally on my computer, they are runing in a container in the same network.

Comment: The error is saying that you are connecting to port 5232 but in docker-compose port 5432 is set.

Comment: If you expose port `5432` you can also try to connect to db on localhost using some client to verify that it is working properly.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelazim But i wonder why is that because if you look at my `application.yml` i'm trying to connect to `5432` maybe i should recreate the `docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: You are connecting to a different port (judging by the error) and I see no password in your `application.yml` nor the reference to `DB_USER` or `DB_PASSWORD` you provide as environment variables.